# How to hide events on monthView?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, events, fullcalendar

Using fullcalendar, I have events on each day. How do I go about hiding those events? I do apologize if this is an duplicate question. Example:[image]

After entering the code that @CodeRomeos  has given. Here is the result:[image]

Another note: the style.css files have not been changed and I pulled them from,
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar

If I do the following to the code, **ALL** events are hidden. I only need events on the monthView to be hidden.
[image][image]

Comment: try `#home-page #calendar .fc-event {
    background-color: #3b91ad;
    border-color: #3b91ad;
    display: none;
}`

Comment: I added that code in the fullcalendar.css (found in bower_components\fullcalendar\dist\) and it did not work.

Comment: It should work. Might be some other issue. Try adding it in your style.css. Also add your code if possible.

Comment: Use your developer tools to figure out whether your style is being applied or not. I think @CodeRomeos answer should work

Comment: Why render them in the first place? Seems simple...if you don't want to see them, don't put them there

Comment: I want events only to rendered in agendaView (day view) but not on the calendar itself.

Answer (score 0):

There was no solution posted nor I found an exact solution. A work around is the following:

```
$scope.uiConfig = {
  calendar:{
    height: 450,
    editable: false,
    selectable: true,
    header:{
      left: 'title',
      center: '',
      right: 'month today prev,next'
    },
    viewRender: function(view){
        $('#myCalendar1').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
    },
    eventClick: $scope.alertOnEventClick,
    eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
    eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,
    eventRender: $scope.eventRender,
    dayClick: $scope.alertOnDateClick,
    timeClick: $scope.alertTest,
    eventWipe: $scope.eventWipe
  }
};
```